# Cannot find symbol .hasNextInt

Tags: java

```
if(args.length != 1){
    System.out.println("Incorrect number of arguments");
    return;
}

String inString = "";
Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(args[0]));

while(s.hasNextInt){
    int temp = s.nextInt();
    inString += temp;
}
```

This is an excerpt of code from my main method. Code won't compile; the two errors are cannot find symbol (s.hasNextInt) and illegal start of type (while(s)). The other question I found here about .hasNextInt and cannot find symbol was someone trying to call .hasNextInt on a string instead of a scanner, and I can't figure out why my scanner can't run hasNextInt. I imported .util and .io.

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `s.hasNextInt()` its a method. Just like the `s.nextInt()` you see how you included the `()` because its a method

Comment: Hmm don't you miss `()`? Should be `s.hasNextInt()`

Comment: Oops, yup. Was missing () in the while loop.

Comment: Are you having further issues moving on? If your problem is solved then you should mark the answer that helped resolving the problem as **accepted**. This helps other people to find what they are looking for. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Sorry, new to stackoverflow. Marked it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the brackets `()` for the method call `hasNextInt()`.

```
while(s.hasNextInt()){
    int temp = s.nextInt();
    inString += temp;
}
```